# How do i split values from dropdownlist and store it in session?

Tags: c#, session

I have a dropdownlist binded with 3 values.
Warehouse Name | Warehousecode |Warehousemasterid
How can i split this `dropdownlist` and store its value in session.

Below is the image of the format of `dropdownlist`

[image: exapmle imaghe]

Comment: on the client side by Javascript? If so, then you can send it to the server by Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Get all values from Dropdownlist:

```
 var ddlArray= new Array();
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl');
    for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
       ddlArray[i] = ddl .options[i].value;
    }
```

**Make Ajax call to the server with this ddlArray as a parameter**. there you can set the server session variable.

If you want to maintain session storage in locally, following code will work.
set session storage to those values:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("yourSessionName",ddlArray);
```

get session storage:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("yourSessionName");
```